# Display same control with same ID in modal popup or page based on viewport size

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a Gridview that need to be displayed in a modal popup or the  page depending on the viewport size.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <asp:GridView   ID="GridView1" >
</div>

<div class="visible-xs">
  <div class="modal-dialog"
    <asp:GridView   ID="GridView1" >
  </div>    
</div>
```

But it results in ID IS IN USE error message. I tried creating Usercontrol; but in vain.

Comment: Info: This is happening due to the id `GridView1` being duplicated.

Comment: I know that. But I do not want to replicate the same gridview code twice.

Comment: @Shankar you can't duplicate the ID of any ASP control but you can assign same data source to two different gridviews